# STM32F302R8 Custom Board Blink an LED Problem

Tags: stm32

I am a new STM32 user migrating from Atmel/Microchip's SAMD line.

I created my first project following along the tutorials here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_5rYfAyqq0&t=682s. It's a motor driver, with some other hardware shown outside of the screenshot below, but at the moment I am just trying to get statusLED to blink. I can successfully connect to the board with an STLink, when I press debug and resume, my LED will momentarily flash which I capture on video and scope, shown in the video here.

Strangely I don't lose connection to the board or anything, and my program continues to execute, but nothing else happens. As you can see from the code it's supposed to just blink every 500ms. Does anyone have an intuition as to what might be going on?

Here's a video showing the momentary flash (The LED is in the bottom right corner of the board and I press the debug/resume buttons off camera)
https://photos.app.goo.gl/BfGQbW1SX8EJT5eV8

I am using the internal clock for debug purposes, and only have Trace Asynchronous Sw debug + the statusLED set as GPIO output. My only added code is:

```
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin (statusLED_GPIO_Port, statusLED_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay (500);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin (statusLED_GPIO_Port, statusLED_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_Delay (500);
```

Also here's the board schematic:
[STM32F302R8 Board Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdMgA.png)

Answer (score 0):

`HAL_Delay` depends on the SysTick interrupt being enabled and hooked up to the HAL.

You need to call `HAL_Init()` from `main()`, which in turn calls `HAL_InitTick()`.

After that you need the function:

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  HAL_IncTick();
}
```

The example projects in the STM32Cube package will include this.

Comment: So from all of the CubeIDE's pre-builts I do call Hal_Init(). For getting to blinking I was really just following along here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ6J8oITgK8

Although that tutorial is using a nucleo not a custom board, do you know if there's a chance some critical HAL level things wouldn't be initialized when using custom hardware?

Answer (score 0):

if you configured your Hardware with CubeMX:

check your CubeMX configuration if your GPIO is set up correctly as "GPIO Output" in "Open Drain" oder "Push Pull" mode. According to the schematics "Open Drain" would be my recomendation, but Push Pull would also work.

One of my favourite mistakes is clicking one line to low in CubeMX, selecting "GPIO_Analog" for the pin instead of "GPIO_Output" and searching the code for a long time for a bug where there is none ;)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Yep I did configure with CubeMX, I double checked that statusLED is indeed a GPIO output, and also tried switching it to Output Open Drain GPIO mode with no luck. Any other ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: then I'd check the electrics / electronics. Does the anode of the LED see the 3.3V? Can you measure the 1 kOhm from the kathode of the LED to the uC pin? And last but not least: check the forward voltage of the LED in the datasheet! if the forward voltage is e.g. 1.7 Volt, the current would be (3.3 - 1.7)/1kOhm = 1.6 mA wich is quite low and could mean, that the LED glows so dim, you might only notice that it's on, when you check that in a dark room. Typically you should try to send at least 5mA through the LED, so a 330 Ohm resistor should be appropriate ...

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be my having pulled up Boot0 with the intention of using a bootloader, and then forgetting about it. So I rotated my Boot0 resistor to be a pulldown and everything is working now.

Still unsure what configuration is going on to get the brief LED flash in the video, but definitely consider this resovled.